# Can't delete the "postgres" user, is missing from /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, centos, postgresql, centos-7, etcpasswd

I'm trying to install Postgresql on a CentOS 7 server.
But when I want to add an user and I execute `sudo -u postgres -i`, nothing happen, not even an error.

The user `postgres` is missing from the `/etc/passwd` file and `/etc/shadow`.
I removed all my postgres configurations from my server and now I'm trying to remove the postgres user.

```
userdel postgres
userdel: cannot remove entry 'postgres' from /etc/passwd
useradd postgres
useradd: user 'postgres' already exists
```

I've tried to manually add a line in /etc/passwd with the uid found by `id postgres`, it remove the line in `/etc/password` but it still exist somehow.

Has anyone have a clue ?

Comment: userdel: cannot remove entry 'postgres' from /etc/passwd -- that doesn't say it doesn't exist. It just says it can't remove it.

Comment: Is this a "standalone" server which you installed the IS on or might it be tied to an authentication system like ldsp?

Comment: There is an authentification system but does it really may impact on the postgres user ?

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't exist in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow, then it doesn't exist.  It could be that removal of the postgres package deletes the user as well.

It's best never edit your passwd and shadow files directory. Try to use utilities which are designed for that purpose (usermod, userdel, passwd, etc.).

It is likely that the postgres user will be generated during the installation of the postgres RPM.  Required system accounts typically are - though I don't have intimate familiarity with postgres specifically.

Comment: In this case, is it normal that after doing a `userdel postgres` if I execute `id postgres` I get this : `uid=3009(postgres) gid=3008(postgres) groups=3008(postgres)` insted of displaying that the user doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `userdel -f`

According to userdel man page:

```
    -f, --force

    This option forces the removal of the user account, even if the user is still logged in. It also forces userdel to remove the user's home directory and mail spool, even if another user uses the same home directory or if the mail spool is not owned by the specified user. If USERGROUPS_ENAB is defined to yes in /etc/login.defs and if a group exists with the same name as the deleted user, then this group will be removed, even if it is still the primary group of another user.
```

Comment: Can you confirm that that will work if the user isn't in /etc/passswd?